# What should I do to make generic size of all UI controls in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I was trying to practice Auto Layout in iOS, and I started with very simple UI. Please see image for understanding my problem.

All the text files are in middle of screen (I have deliberately kept on guide line), still you can see in preview, controls are not fully shown. I have not chosen specific size. Size is '***Inferred***' still I am not able to see all the controls on UI.

I tried both adding and removing Auto Layout, but no luck. What should I do to create generic UI which will work with all the sizes of iPhone and iPad.

[image]

This image is without use of Auto Layout.

Comment: if this image is without the use of auto layout - what do you want us to do? The solution to (almost) all user interface design problems is to use auto layout.

Comment: @luk2302 I tried to add 'Add missing constraints', but no luck.

Comment: Yes, I could have told you that as well - *YOU* have to create the constraints, that is nothing a machine can do for you - read up on autolayout, get clear on what the desired design should look and *all* supported devices and then add the constraints to achieve that design. There is not shortcut.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but when I strictly place control in center, shouldn't it come to center in all the devices. Am I accepting wrong thing. I read auto layout and now trying to practice it. From last 2 hours I stuck with this problem.

Comment: No, it should not - if will have the same spacing to the left on all devices. 2 years? You can get complex auto layouts working in less than a week.

Comment: @luk2302 Really sorry, it was 2 hours, I edited my comment.

Comment: Well, 2 hours could get you somewhere - just dont *assume* anything. Every size and position should be specified by *you*.

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for comments, I think I need to spend some more time understanding Auto Layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enable autolayout and size classes you have to apply autolayout constraints.

Autolayout is a detail topic. Few basic things when applying autolayout is:

UI element need four constraints.

1. position x
2. Position y
3. height
4. width

So you will select first label (Number 1). Then press control and drag to superview. You will be provide options. Select **Leading space** (This will handle x position)

This is the way you can press control and drag:

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/auto-layout-login-trailing.gif

Go to size inspector. You can see the constraint.

[image]

Press edit and change its value to 25(for test).

similarly control and drag again to superview and select **Top space**. (This will set y position for label)

This is simple way for the above taken from AppCoda

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/auto-layout-control-drag.gif

You can change the value of these constraints according to your need.

UILabel and uitextfield get width and height from their content size. So don't need width and height constraints.

Now when you preview on any device this label will be stick on top left side of screen.

So this is a complete mechanism. You have to apply constraint to every ui element.

Below is a link to very comprehensive tutorial by

http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

At start this tutorial tried to create three views using autolayout. At the end it shows very similar scenario like yours by applying constraints to button and labels.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your constraints are not set correctly to work with every size of iPhone and iPad. You are setting the leading edge constraint to be a fixed size from your view controller's view to the subviews.

The simplest way to solve this issue would be to have a container view that you center in the view controller's view and then use constraints to set 'Center X Alignment Constraint' and 'Center Y Alignment Constraint' to set the container view's center to that of the view controller and then add your subviews to the container view.

As a side note auto layout has a reputation of being hard to learn, you have to put the time in to learn it, I would start with Apple's  [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html).

[image]